# SQL Server installation prerequisite fails

Tags: sql-server, setup

When I install SQL Server 2008 R2, I get this message:

> Previous release of Microsoft Visual Studio 2008  -- Failed

([screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SD0nA.jpg))

I can't proceed to the next step. How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe `View detailed report` or `Failed` link to information that helps you. What have you tried?

Comment: first MS SQL Server should be installed, then MS Visual Studio. Otherwise it may show error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an error which shows that an MS SQL Server install should come before  Visual Studio.
This issue occurs when you install first Visual Studio 2008 then your try to install SQL Server 2008 R2. For fixing this issue follow below steps:

1. download Visual Studio 2008 sp1
2. then install SP1
3. after it install SQL Server

(or)

1. uninstall Visual Studio 2008 from your machine and install SQL Server
2. install SQL Server AND then install Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

There is no error after I uninstall MS Visual studio 2008 and install SQL server again !